# Flutter web file upload

Tags: php, flutter

```
void _uploadFile(Event event) async {
    print("called");
    final files = uploadInput.files;
    final file = files![0];
    _fileNameController.text = file.name;

    // Get the file contents as a List<int>
    final reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    await reader.onLoad.first;
    final contents = reader.result as List<int>;

    // Encode the file contents as a base64 string
    final encodedFile = base64Encode(contents);

    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse("http://url/img_test/img.php"),
        body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
          'file': encodedFile,
        })
    );

    print(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Handle the success case
      print("ok");
    } else {
      // Handle the error case
      print("try");
    }
  }
```

I all ready set as file in body but till it shows
Error shows in flutter
**Warning**:  Undefined array key "file" in **M:\WEB\htdocs\img_test\img.php** on line **7**

PHP API:

```
<?php
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

your request post not send file, this string value, you can try decode in your php file like this

```
$base64string = "data:image/jpeg;base64,".$POST['file'];
list($type, $base64string) = explode(';', $base64string);
list(,$extension)          = explode('/',$type);
list(,$base64string)       = explode(',', $base64string);
$fileName                  = uniqid()'.'.$extension;
$imageFile                 = base64_decode($base64string);
file_put_contents($path.$fileName, $imageFile);
```